# Network programming through c Compiling and executing but not printing IP address...!

Tags: c, api, sockets, networking, network-programming

Here am including the code I have written The code compiles and executes but the ip addresses are not printing out instead am getting the below output. and I have included the code below please help me.

```
  //This is the executed code printed out  
    -Inspiron-1318:~$ ./com2 google.com
    Networks use Big Endian order

    This machine uses Little Endian


    google.com to 
    // here I need to print the ip addresses but I am unable to//
```

This is the code I have written; please help me find my mistakes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void checkEndian()
{
    uint32_t a=0x10de7623;
    uint32_t b = ntohl(a);
    if(b == a)
    {
        printf("This machine uses Big Endian\n");
    } 
    else if(b ==0x2376de10 )
    {
        printf("\nThis machine uses Little Endian\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This machine uses Other Endian\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("Networks use Big Endian order\n");
    checkEndian();

    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("expected a name for resolving");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *name=argv[1];
    char ip[100];

    name_ip(name , ip);
    printf("%s to %s\n",name,ip); 
}

int name_ip(char *name,char *ip)
{
    struct addrinfo hints , *answer , *h;
    char buf[1024];

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 

    int error = getaddrinfo(name, NULL, &hints, &answer);

    if(error!=0)
    {
    fprintf(stderr,"\n error in getaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(error));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(h = answer; h != NULL; h = h->ai_next)
    {
    if(h->ai_family=AF_INET)
    {
    struct sockaddr_in *x;

    x=(struct sockaddr_in *)h->ai_addr;

    //// this inet_ntop is the root of whole problem//
    inet_ntop(h->ai_family,&(((struct sockaddr_in *)h->ai_addr)->sin_addr),buf,1024);

    }

    if(hints.ai_family=AF_INET6)
    {
    struct sockaddr_in6 *x;

    x=(struct sockaddr_in6*)h->ai_addr;
    // this inet_ntop is the root of whole problem//

    inet_ntop(h->ai_family,&(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)h->ai_addr)->sin6_addr),buf,1024);
    }
    printf("%s\n",ip);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please reduce your code to minimal example and format it appropriately.

Comment: Note that the `checkEndian()` code is completely tangential to the question on SO, though it might conceivably be needed for your submission to your course tutor.  It would be best if omitted.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error, of which there are two occurrences:

```
if(h->ai_family=AF_INET)
```

As it is an *assignment*, not an equality check. Use `==` instead:

```
if(h->ai_family==AF_INET)
```

Additionally, `ip` is never populated in the function `name_ip()`.